# PHP form POST working fine on ASO. Throws Internal Server Error (500) after migrating to Crazy Domains

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a simple PHP form that was working fine on my ASO Hosting. After cloning the website on client hosting (Crazy Domains); it still sends the email perfectly but console is returning a 500 error. Any ideas?

```
<?php
    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "example@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: [22-Apr-2015 21:39:16 Australia/Perth] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function http_response_code() in /home10/metasurg/public_html/wp-content/themes/metasurgical/mailer.php on line 34

Comment: There you go! All you have to do is *fix it*.